# Electron read file from dialog box getting type error

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am writing an electron program that needs to read a file for me to apply another program onto. For now I just want it to successfully read and log the content of the file.

this is the code i am using in a script called script.js, which is included in a script tag in the index.html

```
// dialog box
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;
// file system, needed to read contents of the ecgFile
const {fs} = require('fs');

const dialogOptions = {properties:['openFile']}

// bool for checking if file has been selected
let isFileSelected = false;
let ecgFile; // content of the ecgFile itself

// Buttons
const openFileBtn = document.getElementById('openFileBtn');

// on click event, opens the dialog box and loads content of the file
openFileBtn.onclick = () =>
{
  console.log("start")

  let filePathArray = dialog.showOpenDialogSync({properties: ['openFile']}) // output the filepath of the file selected
  let filePath = filePathArray[0] // set to the first object in the array, which is what is needed
  console.log("File Location -- "+ filePath) // print to check its hunky dory
  readFile(filePath) // read the file
  console.log("End")
};

function readFile(filePath) 
{
  fs.readFile(filePath,{"encoding": "utf8"},(err,data) =>
  {
    if (err)
    {
      console.log("Cannot read file",err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Content of data: ")
    console.log(data);    
  }
  )
}
```

I am able to successfully print the filePath that I want to use, and the issue is when I pass that filePath to the readFile function

When it runs the readFile function, it always outputs this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined
    at readFile (script.js:55)
    at HTMLButtonElement.openFileBtn.onclick (script.js:23)
```

I have looked for solutions to no success. Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fs` import cannot be [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring).

replace

```js
const {fs} = require('fs');
```

with

```js
const fs = require('fs');
```